# Height of <li> elements equal to height of <navigation>

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 80%;
  height: 20%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: green;
}

.image {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.navigation {
  width: 79%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

li {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <div class="image">
    Image
  </div>

  <nav class="navigation">
    <li> 1.0 Main Menu </li>
    <li> 2.0 Main Menu </li>
    <li> 3.0 Main Menu </li>
  </nav>

</div>
```

With the code above I create a `<header>` consisting of an `<image>` and a `<navigation>`. The `<image>` and the `<navigation>` match perfectly with the height of the surrounding `<header>`.

Inside the `<navigation>` I put some `<li>` elements and I want them to have the **same height** as the surrounding `<navigation>`. Therefore, I gave them the property `height: 100%;` which I also did for the `<image>` and the `<navigation>` but it does not seem to work.

What do I have to change in my code so the `<li>` elements match the height of the surrounding `<navigation>` element?

You can also find my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/5jv8m5xf/28/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `inline-block` instead of `inline` for the `display` property for the list element.

Comment: Hi Thomas, it looks good. The only issue that appears when I put inline-block instead of inline is that I get a space between the items. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/5jv8m5xf/29/ How can I get rid of this space?

Comment: Well this is there because it treats the elements like words and these have spaces in between. Use `float: left;` or `float: right;` to solve that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. What exactly is the difference between inline and inline-block?

Comment: As you can guess it's a hybrid. Acting as an inline element but with the possible settings of a block element.

Answer (score 1):

Change *display* property of `li` to `inline-block` instead of `inline` and to solve the overlapping divs, you can use `box-sizing: border-box` for all the elements.

To remove the *space between the `li`s* you can set `font-size: 0` to the `nav` and *reset* it for the `li`.

See demo below:

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 80%;
  height: 20%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: green;
}

.image {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.navigation {
  width: 79%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-size: 0;
}

li {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <div class="image">
    Image
  </div>

  <nav class="navigation">
    <li> 1.0 Main Menu </li>
    <li> 2.0 Main Menu </li>
    <li> 3.0 Main Menu </li>
  </nav>

</div>
```

Comment: Nice trick with the font-size: initial. I just found the solutions here https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ but prefer your way to go since it seems the most flexible one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make "li" display: inline-block to be able to take the full height and make the border-width: 0 because if you make it 1 the "li" will be more height that the nav:

```
li {
 height: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0px;
 background-color: blue;
}
```