# Can´t set border radius on one side and a regular border on the opposite side

Tags: html, css, border, inline, display

For some reason, my regular semi-transparent right border doesn´t work on the element which has border-radius on the left and bottom sides. How can I fix it?

See snippet and [`codepen`](https://codepen.io/HernanF/pen/OdEeMZ):

```css
body {
  background: red;
}

.item {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.box {
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  line-height: 10px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  background: white;
}

.border {
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box border">
    <p class="item"> Origen</p>
    <p class="item"> Buenos Aires</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p class="item"> Origen</p>
    <p class="item"> Buenos Aires</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p class="item"> Origen</p>
    <p class="item"> Buenos Aires</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use *negative* margins to remove the *space between `inline` elements*. Set `font-size` to zero for the `container` and reset it for the `box` - see how the issue is *solved* by itself now:

```css
body {
  background: red;
}

.item {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#container {
  font-size: 0; /* ADDED */
}

.box {
  font-size: initial; /* ADDED */
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  line-height: 10px;
  /*margin-left: -5px;*/
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  background: white;
}

.border {
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box border">
    <p class="item"> Origen</p>
    <p class="item"> Buenos Aires</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p class="item"> Origen</p>
    <p class="item"> Buenos Aires</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p class="item"> Origen</p>
    <p class="item"> Buenos Aires</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Why does this work though? I´m new to this, so an explanation would be really helpful!

Comment: That is just the *characteristic* space between inline elements.. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40630148/inexplicable-offsets-in-some-very-basic-html/40630355#40630355) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782157/height-of-li-elements-equal-to-height-of-navigation/45782234#45782234) for an example

Comment: @ReduxNewbie check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40630148/inexplicable-offsets-in-some-very-basic-html/40630355#40630355) too...

Comment: Thanks a lot! These exchanges are the best way to learn.

Comment: It´s because of margin collapse which overrides the border, right?

Comment: no you are having *negative margins* to account for the *space between inline elements*... margin collapsing is a different concept :)

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. So basically with the negative margins (since inline-block behaves like text) the divs collapse so the border is lost.

Comment: yeah, that is right :)